# ContentCachingRequestWrapper getContentAsByteArray() method return only 8000 bytes

Tags: spring

I`m using ContentCachingRequestWrapper to cache my request in Spring Boot filter. Unfortunatelly, when I use method getContentAsByteArray() to get content of my request - I get only array with size 8000 bytes.

I haven`t got any post limit in Tomcat. What is more, when I check size of request earlier - it is correct.

Do you know why  ContentCachingRequestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray() return only 8000 bytes?

Code:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
//here --> requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray().length = 8000 (for larger request)      


savemyRequest(new String(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray()), response.getStatus());

}
```

Comment: Can yo ushare some of your code?

Comment: I`ve just edited my post

Comment: Looks fine. But to get request body to be cached this way - all request body should be read first somewhere. By Spring converters, for example. What is the content type of you requests? What is going on with them in Spring controller? Can you share some of this part too?

Comment: This link may help - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14829 - There is a setting to limit the content to prevent Out-of-memory (OOM). Hopes this help.

Comment: @Minh Kieu, thanks but I`ve already tried set contentCacheLimit. It is really weird because when I set for example limit to 15000 - the method returns array with length 8000, but when I set it to f.e 3000- it works, the length is 3000.

Comment: @Leffchik Thanks. My request is json. I did it in this way, because I want to save my request + response http status. It is very weird because when I tried to get size of request like this: requestWrapper.getContentLength(); - it returns correct size (>8000 bytes).

Comment: If your content is only 3000 then why it return 8000? and what are in the 5000 part? BTW, if you got a stream content then getting the contentLength may not be correct. Stream content will fill up the buffer and push (flush) part-by-part. Are you rely on the number return by the content length method? Have you tried read the JSON object and see if you have all the content?

Comment: @Minh Kieu, When I set a contentCacheLimit to 3000 it has 3000, when I set to 10000 it has 8000 (always, even if I send a 10mb request). Yes, I`m parsing json to object and everything works correct (my requests are <3000bytes, so It is not a problem for me), but I wanted to know why getContentAsByteArray() return max 8000 bytes

Comment: Possible 8000 is the upper limit to prevent OOM. You can try downloading the source and step into the code?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and decided to keep what I got here.
People in the comments already mentioned a bit.

**ContentCachingRequestWrapper** itself does not read the request body. It wraps the request body with (as class name implies) [PushBackInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html). As soon as the request body is read (somewhere after filters), then a copy of the data is cached in **ContentCachingRequestWrapper**.

In my case issue was the next: Request body was started to be converted by
[MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html). Reading of request body and converting to the Java Object happened in a gradual way: first part (8000bytes) read - first part converted, ... . Then conversion exception happened and then I got only 8000bytes in a controller exception handler (@ExceptionHandler) - part of the request body that was read by a converter.